# how to get id of a select box in table that is dynamically generated

Tags: jquery, select

Hi I am having a table which will be populating dynamically. It has a select box which on select should open pop but I dont know the id of the selected row. How can I know the select item from which it is been selected.

```
<table>
<tr id="<%=columnId%>" >
<td class="lic-3-4"><%=columnName%></td>
<td id="datatype" class="lic-3-4"><%=dataType%></td>
<td class="lic-5-4"><div ><select class="mol-select-tc" name="action_col1" id=""<%=columnId%>"></select></div></td>
</tr>
<tr id="<%=columnId%>" >
<td class="lic-3-4"><%=columnName%></td>
<td id="datatype" class="lic-3-4"><%=dataType%></td>
<td class="lic-5-4"><div ><select class="mol-select-tc" name="action_col1" id=""<%=columnId%>"></select></div></td>
</tr>
        <tr id="<%=columnId%>" >
<td class="lic-3-4"><%=columnName%></td>
<td id="datatype" class="lic-3-4"><%=dataType%></td>
<td class="lic-5-4"><div ><select class="mol-select-tc" name="action_col1" id=""<%=columnId%>"></select></div></td>
</tr>
</table>

 var selectedAlgSelect = $('#action_col1');//here I want the select the dynamically //generated id of select column
     selectedAlgSelect.die('change').live('change',function(){  
         var rowEl = $(this).closest('tr');      
          var currentRow = $(rowEl);
          var dataType = currentRow.find('td[id=datatype]').text();
           var selectEl = currentRow.find('select[name=action_col1]').val();
    }
```

Comment: You cannot access an element until it gets attached to `DOM`.So make sure your `select` element is attached before accessing it.

Comment: its is attached. I load the page and it shows table with select boxes .Now I select 1 item in one of the row. I should be able to get selected row values.

Comment: Please clarify your question : what is the expected result ? what doesn't work as expected ?

Comment: i want to know which select box i had selected

Comment: you don't know because your IDs are empty - id=""<%=columnId%>" - double qoutes

Answer (score 1):

This is working

```
var selectedAlgSelect =  $('select');
     selectedAlgSelect.die('change').live('change',function(){  
......
}
```